# Visual Studio Code insert blank line after list item on save

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown

When editing a Markdown document in Visual Studio Code such as:

````
1. Example
```bash
$ cat dummy.txt
```
````

On save, the editor will automatically insert a blank line after the list item like this:

````
1. Example

```bash
$ cat dummy.txt
```
````

Do you know how to configure Visual Studio Code not to insert a blank line after the list item?

Answer (score 1):

You likely have a formatter (and likely [this formatter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DavidAnson.vscode-markdownlint)) enabled for Markdown files.  If you look in your settings.JSON file, you may see something like this in it:

```json
{
  "[markdown]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "DavidAnson.vscode-markdownlint"
  }
}
```

The reason it is fixing this for you is because it's following the linting rules of "*fenced code blocks should be surrounded by blank lines*":

[image: markdown lint rule]

You can delete this JSON out your settings, and it should no longer do this, but you will lose other automatic formatting as well.  Alternatively, you can configure this as described in the linked documentation:

> Rules can be enabled, disabled, and customized by creating a JSON file named .markdownlint.jsonc/.markdownlint.json or a YAML file named .markdownlint.yaml/.markdownlint.yml or a JavaScript file named .markdownlint.cjs in any directory of a project.

In your case, you'd want `MD031` disabled since that controls the linting for blanks around code fences:

```json
{
    "MD031": false
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your pointer, @timothy-g. I realized the Mardown file is formatted by Prettier extension when checking the formatter as you explained. I will post this question with `prettier` tag.